# How to load selected pages in android webview?

Tags: android, android-webview

I am currently working on android webview applications. I was wondering if there is a way to load selected pages only in android webview, like just tell the app to load only specific pages,not whole website. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends on what you mean by specific pages.  You can lock the webview into only a set of URLs by overriding shouldOverrideUrlLoading to return true and just not load any URLs you don't want to.  If you mean you want to not load part of a URL I don't think there's a way to do that.